# Cassandra Query column mapping

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, cassandra-2.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Cassandra table `trans_by_date` with columns origin, `tran_date` (and some other columns). I try to run the below code get error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table trans.trans_by_date : TRAN_DATE.  The column does exist.
```

Any syntax gotcha?

```
JavaRDD<TransByDate> transDateRDD = javaFunctions(sc)
.cassandraTable("trans", "trans_by_date", CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(TransByDate.class))
.select(CassandraJavaUtil.column("origin"), CassandraJavaUtil.column("TRAN_DATE").as("transdate"));


 public static class TransByDate implements Serializable {
        private String origin;
        private Date transdate;

    public String getOrigin() { return origin; }
        public void setOrigin(String id) { this.origin = id; }

        public Date getTransdate() { return transdate; }
        public void setTransdate(Date trans_date) { this.transdate = trans_date; }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change CassandraJavaUtil.column("TRAN_DATE") to CassandraJavaUtil.column("tran_date"), i.e. only use lower-case column names, your code should work.

It seems that the CassandraJavaUtil puts the column name into double quotes when creating the select query.

See the following link for uppercase and lowercase handling in cassandra:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/ucase-lcase_r.html

Comment: setting to lower case solved that problem. Then new issues arose: `Failed to map constructor parameter id in class spark.SparkTest$TransByDate to a column of trans.trans_by_date
Failed to map constructor parameter tran_date in class spark.SparkTest$TransByDate to a column of trans.trans_by_date` So I had change the both method variables names - id  to origin, and tran_date to trandate - to match the class variable names. Well if that is the only way it works.

Comment: @Sam-T Sorry, but I think adding the answer to the original questions is not the way this forum is intended to work. Now nobody else understand the question and the answer doesn't match any longer. I would propose to revert the change you've done and add the information as additional comment to my answer.

Comment: @Sam-T Thanks, for reverting your changes to the question. I couldn't reproduce the second issue you had with the _Failed to map constructor parameter_ message. Maybe it depends on the version of the spark-cassandra-connector (I use version 1.6). As the original issue is fixed by my answer, could you mark the answer as correct? Then other users know that the question is resolved.

Comment: Done, I am using Cassandra 2.2.8